# Problemas de Directorios en Android Studio comportamiento visual Erratico

Tags: android, programación-móvil

capaz esto sea algo basico y no muy grave, pero me incomoda que haya actualizado a la nueva version de android Studio y lo vea de esta forma los directorios [image: Como se logra visualizar "com.....addtasks" el otro en vez de que esten en una sola carpeta los separa de manera no comprensiva esto es algo nuevo que ocurrio, alguien tiene la solucion?]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno buscando solucion a mi problema, espero si alguien le pasa esto, es verificar en su configuracion como en la imagen adjunta

[image]

Comment: ¿Qué opción en específico cambiaste? Por cierto, prueba con activar la opción `Flatten Packages` o `Compact Middle Packages`.